# How to set date format, timezone and locale using angular 4 date pipe?

Tags: angular, timezone, locale, date-pipe

I have date value from `postgres` db without timezone. I want this display in angular 2 template with timezone and locale

```
postgres db value : 2017-11-14 09:40:59.753
```

I just displayed date in angular template using `{{codeset.created_on}}` it will be displayed below like :

```
Tue Nov 14 2017 09:40:59 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

But I want display current time based on timezone with locale

I tried like below in angular template :

```
<span>{{codeset.created_on | date :'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a' :'+530' :'en-US'}}</span>
```

Comment: Old question but I had a similar problem. Hope the following help someone in the future because it took me a while to figure out. I used Angular 7 but the DatePipe format is the same.

When my application parsed JSON -response from API, the date-time strings not included a timezone. So then angular parsed date-strings to local time already. My fix was to use the following response format in API endpoints: `2019-07-31T14:00:00Z`

Simple fix but was hard to figure out. After that, template pipe parameters worked well because not it was converted first to UTC timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it globally by providing `LOCALE_ID` to your app. In your `app.module.ts` for example:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [
    ...
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'nl-NL' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
```

Comment: It is another possibility but not the solution he is asking for. He wants to put the locale in the template.